# Error trying to add Arrays to an ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

So I was trying to add 2 dimensional arrays to an array list like this:

```
public class game{

        static ArrayList<Object> edges = new ArrayList<Object>();

        static void setEdges(){
            for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<8;j++){
                    edges.add( {9*i+j,9*i+j+1} );
                    edges.add( {9*i+j , 9*i+j+9} );
                }
            }
        }
   }
```

But it doesn't work. What does  seem to work is this:

```
public class game{

        static ArrayList<Object> edges = new ArrayList<Object>();

        static void setEdges(){
            for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<8;j++){
                    int[] edge = {9*i+j,9*i+j+1};
                    int [] edge2 = {9*i+j , 9*i+j+9};
                    edges.add( edge2 );
                    edges.add( edge );
                }
            }
        }
   }
```

I can't understand why the simplest method doesn't work but the other does.

Comment: Why are you using `Object` instead of `int[]`?

Comment: Because I didn't know what types you could write inside the < - >.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because what you had written is not valid Java syntax:

```
edges.add( {9*i+j,9*i+j+1} );
edges.add( {9*i+j , 9*i+j+9} );
```

You need to explicitly specify that you're adding an array:

```
edges.add(new int[] {9 * i + j, 9 * i + j + 1});
edges.add(new int[] {9 * i + j, 9 * i + j + 9});
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that normal because you trying to add a Integer into a intense to the array of object (edges) with out cast. So if you want that work replace Object by Integer  :)